# XSL-FO: external-graphic with intternet image

Tags: xml, facebook, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We are using Apache FOP to produce a PDF from an XML file. 
The XML can contain a link to a facebook profile image, but the path is in fact a redirection.

The following does not work, it uses the path we have in XML file:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('http://graph.facebook.com/<some id nbs>/picture"') />
```

The following works:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/<some id>_n.jpg?oh=<some id>"') />
```

However, it is impossible to hard-code every true URI. 
How can I force FO to follow the link? 
Otherwise, maybe there is a way to retrieve the image from the 1st URI?

Thanks for your answers. XSL-FO can be really painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

- using `src="url('http://...')"` won't work
- using directly the url will work `src="http://..."`

However, still doesn't work with Facebook pictures. Works fine with twitter, instagram...

Answer (score 1):

You should call the image url `https://graph.facebook.com/<some id nbs>/picture?redirect=false` in your application and then extract the content of the `url` property of the resulting JSON.

Comment: Ok so I should "convert" via the application, and then send this to the XML. I can't make XSL do that, can I? :(